# Django i18n not working on python files

Tags: django, internationalization

Django newbie here,

I'm using Django's i18n to translate my website.

My templates get translated just fine using the `trans` template tag

However, when I try to translate strings in my python files, for instance this form field's label:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class RegForm(forms.Form):
    form_field = forms.CharField(label=_('My field'))
```

It does not get translated.
The same page contains other template strings that do get translated..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use ugettext_lazy instead of gettext